# How can a service MBean depend on singleton stateless session bean using jboss-service.xml in wildfly 8

Tags: java, wildfly-8, mbeans, ejb-3.2

I am trying to provide a `service mbean` a `singleton stateless session bean` by configuring in `jboss-service.xml`using `<depends>` in wildfly AS 8 but getting the below error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "TestEAR.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.mbean.service.TestService.start is missing [jboss.mbean.service.\"jboss.j2ee:ear=TestEAR.ear,jar=module-A.jar,name=TestConfig,service=EJB3\".start]",
"jboss.mbean.service.TestService.create is missing [jboss.mbean.service.\"jboss.j2ee:ear=TestEAR.ear,jar=module-A.jar,name=TestConfig,service=EJB3\".create]"
```

Please find below the details on the code employed: Please help me to resolve the error. Many thanks.

**project structure**

TestEAR (ear)

--- module-A (ejb jar containing singleton stateless session bean)

--- module-B (jar containing service mbean)

**singleton stateless session bean (under module-A JAR)**

```
@Local(TestLocal.class)
@Resource(name="TestConfig", mappedName="java:/ConnectionFactory")
public class TestConfig {
... code ...
}
```

**jboss-service.xml (under meta-inf folder in TestEAR.ear)**

```
<server>
<mbean code="com.test.TestService" name="TestService">
<depends>jboss.j2ee:ear=TestEAR.ear,jar=module-A.jar,name=TestConfig,service=EJB3</depends>
</mbean>
```

**TestService.java (MBean) (under module-B JAR)**

```
public class TestService extends ServiceMBeanSupport implements TestMBean { 
protected void startService() throws Exception {
...code...
}
protected void stopService() throws Exception {
...code...
}
protected void createService() throws Exception {
...code...
}
protected void destroyService() throws Exception {
...code...
}
}
```

**TestMBean.java (MBean interface) (under module-B JAR)**

```
public interface TestMBean extends org.jboss.system.ServiceMBean { }
```